# Install TPOT on RHEL server

Tags: python, linux, redhat, rhel

i am trying to install xgboost and TPOT on a Red Hat server, but it refuses to do so with pip3. i currently get an error of which these are the most important parts.

```
 copying xgboost/CMakeLists.txt -> build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/xgboost
 copying xgboost/LICENSE -> build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/xgboost
 INFO:XGBoost build_ext:Building from source. /tmp/pip-build-uvm9zqkr/lib/libxgboost.so
 INFO:XGBoost build_ext:Run CMake command: ['cmake', 'xgboost', '-GUnix Makefiles', '-DUSE_OPENMP=1', 
'-DUSE_CUDA=0', '-DUSE_NCCL=0', '-DBUILD_WITH_SHARED_NCCL=0', '-DHIDE_CXX_SYMBOLS=1', '-DUSE_HDFS=0', 
'-DUSE_AZURE=0', '-DUSE_S3=0', '-DPLUGIN_LZ4=0', '-DPLUGIN_DENSE_PARSER=0',  
  DUSE_SYSTEM_LIBXGBOOST=0']
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake': 'cmake'
```

---

```
Failed building wheel for xgboost
Running setup.py clean for xgboost
Failed to build xgboost
Installing collected packages: xgboost, tpot
Running setup.py install for xgboost ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip- 
build-uvm9zqkr/xgboost/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-3em2gmv0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -- 
compile:
 running install
 running build
 running build_py
 creating build
 creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
 creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/xgboost

INFO:XGBoost build_ext:Run CMake command: ['cmake', 'xgboost', '-GUnix Makefiles', '-DUSE_OPENMP=1', '-DUSE_CUDA=0', '-DUSE_NCCL=0', '-DBUILD_WITH_SHARED_NCCL=0', '-DHIDE_CXX_SYMBOLS=1', '-DUSE_HDFS=0', '-DUSE_AZURE=0', '-DUSE_S3=0', '-DPLUGIN_LZ4=0', '-DPLUGIN_DENSE_PARSER=0', '-DUSE_SYSTEM_LIBXGBOOST=0']
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake': 'cmake'
```

---

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build- 
uvm9zqkr/xgboost/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-3em2gmv0- 
 record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in 
 /tmp/pip-build-uvm9zqkr/xgboost/
```

I have succeeded in installing xgboost on the server via git. I can't install TPOT via git because the install seems to be written for Debian systems only, leaving me at al loss for what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggest that you need to install cmake.

Comment: I already have, But it doesn't seem to be able to find the package for some reason, could it be that it is in a different place from where it is searched for.

Comment: Where is the binary installed?  Is that directory in your PATH?